# How to force smooth rendering of WPF Controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, rendering

I am creating a simple WPF Application, which should combine a couple of images within a scrollable area. These images should have absolutely no border, which should be no problem when simply positioning them correctly.

When I start the application, everything is rendered as intended. But when I start scrolling some (white) borders between the images occur. (See Screenshot)

[image: Example where unexpected border occur]

I think the same problem would occur, when i start zooming/scaling inside the `ScrollViewer`.

So my question is, how to avoid such borders, wihtin a WPF application and especially within a `ScrollViewer`?

The following code should be enough to reproduce the problem:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="scrollViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid Background="Black" Width="500" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Grid Background="Black" Width="500" Height="500" Margin="500,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Grid Background="Black" Width="500" Height="500" Margin="500,500,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Grid Background="Black" Width="500" Height="500" Margin="0,500,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You need to post code or privide a sample project that reproduces this to even be able to test it. For all we could guess, It could be the machine with limited resources. You could if possible form a **new** image that consist of the 4 original images and put this new image in your `ScrollViewer`. You shouldn't have such issues then since in the View, you're only dealing with 1 image but in the background you can keep track of which area of the image corresponds to which source.

Comment: I've added a simple code example above. Which shows the same problem using some grids. Combining the images to one image is not intended! Limited resources are definitly not the problem of my machine.

Comment: Your code to reproduce the issue does **not** cause the issue your having for me on my machine. I just have a black area with no white borders in the intersection area while scrolling or without(or I'm blind to it)

Comment: Although I'm currently unable to reproduce the issue, I remember that I once solved an issue of this kind by setting [EdgeMode.Aliased](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.edgemode.aspx).

Comment: Yes this is correct - this is the solution. I've found this solution by meself and posted it already below. But thank you too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is explicitly setting the `RenderOptions.EdgeMode` to `Aliased` for the control that has such a border.

For my example above the code would look like this:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="scrollViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid Background="Black" Width="500" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"/>
            <Grid Background="Black" Width="500" Height="500" Margin="500,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"/>
            <Grid Background="Black" Width="500" Height="500" Margin="500,500,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"/>
            <Grid Background="Black" Width="500" Height="500" Margin="0,500,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```